# How to use an observable collection and notifyproperty changed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to wpf and i am currently trying to play with grid and adding subtracting,removing elements to a db table which eventually binds to a grid.

So select from grid, update observable collection, refresh.

I am failing to understand how can i use change notifications of observable collection.

Here is my code

Class which binds to grid

```
  public class students
{
   ObservableCollection<GetStudents_Result> stdb = new ObservableCollection<GetStudents_Result>();



   //public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;


   public students()
   {


       AbcdEntities abcdEnt=new AbcdEntities();

       List<GetStudents_Result> studentColl = abcdEnt.GetStudents().ToList();
       foreach (var item in studentColl)
       {
           stdb.Add(item);
       }
   }

   //public  void onCollectionChange(object sender,NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler e)
   //{

   //}

   public ObservableCollection<GetStudents_Result> std {get {return stdb;}}
}
```

my xaml.

```
 <Canvas>
    <TextBox Height="23" Canvas.Top="5" Canvas.Left="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <TextBox Height="23" Canvas.Top="30" Canvas.Left="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Button Canvas.Left="90" Canvas.Top="65" Content="Remove" Click="button2_Click" Height="23" Name="button2" Width="75" />
    <Button Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="65" Content="Save" Height="23" Name="button1" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />

    <ListView Name="listviewStudents" Canvas.Top="100" ItemsSource="{Binding std}" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>                     
                <GridViewColumn Header="fname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=fname}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="lname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=lname}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=address}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=phno}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=radio}"></GridViewColumn>

            </GridView>

        </ListView.View>

    </ListView>

</Canvas>
```

my code behind

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        students std = new students();
        this.DataContext = std;
    }

    private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        GetStudents_Result selectedItem = listviewStudents.SelectedItem as GetStudents_Result;
        textBox1.Text = selectedItem.fname;
        textBox2.Text = selectedItem.lname;


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GetStudents_Result selecteditem = listviewStudents.SelectedItem as GetStudents_Result;
        selecteditem.fname = textBox1.Text;
        selecteditem.lname = textBox2.Text;
        listviewStudents.Items.Refresh();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listviewStudents.Items.Remove(listviewStudents.SelectedItem);
        listviewStudents.Items.Refresh();
    }
}
```

}

pardon for any stupid mistakes..

Comment: What is exactly your problem?

Comment: And why is your observable collection named STD? That's just wrong xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a a coulpe of problems here, you should not have to touch the `UI` controls from the code behind, you should be using data binding.

Here is a working example of model binding based on your post.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // set the DataContext to the code in this window
        this.DataContext = this;

        // create youe Student model
        StudentModel = new students();
    }


    // Create a public property of your student Model
    private students _studentModel;
    public students StudentModel
    { 
        get { return _studentModel; }
        set { _studentModel = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("StudentModel"); }
    }

    // create a public property to use as the selected item from your models "std" collection
    private GetStudents_Result _selectedResult;
    public GetStudents_Result SelectedResult 
    {
        get { return _selectedResult; }
        set { _selectedResult = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedResult"); }
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // if you want to remove an item you just have to remove it from
        // the model, the INotifyPropertyChanged interface will notify the UI
        // to update, no need to call Refresh, same works for Add etc
        StudentModel.std.Remove(SelectedResult);
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the `xaml` we can bind the `ListView` to your `StudentModel` collection and the `SelectedResult`

```
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding StudentModel.std}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedResult}" >
```

And for the `TextBoxes` you can bind to the `SelectedResult` so it will update the details for you

**Note:** In this example it updates the SelectedResult when the text changes, you can change this as you wish.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedResult.Fname, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedResult.Lname, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

So now when you select an item from the `ListView` these `TextBoxes` will be populated, and when they are changed the `SelectedResult` item will be changed.

Now, for adding and removing Items in your `ListView`, you just have to add and remove from your `StudentModel`collection (StudentModel.std).

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StudentModel.std.Remove(SelectedResult);
}
```

**Note:** This event handler should be an `ICommand` binding, but i will let your search for that :)

Here is a Full example tha hopefully helps explaining the basics of `WPF MVVM`

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        StudentModel = new students();
    }

    private students _studentModel;
    public students StudentModel
    { 
        get { return _studentModel; }
        set { _studentModel = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("StudentModel"); }
    }

    private GetStudents_Result _selectedResult;
    public GetStudents_Result SelectedResult 
    {
        get { return _selectedResult; }
        set { _selectedResult = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedResult"); }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StudentModel.std.Remove(SelectedResult);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}

public class students
{
    public students()
    {
        std = new ObservableCollection<GetStudents_Result>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            std.Add(new GetStudents_Result { Fname = "FirstName" + i, Lname = "LasrName" + i });
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<GetStudents_Result> std { get; set; }
}

public class GetStudents_Result : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _fname;
    private string _lname;

    public string Fname
    {
        get { return _fname; }
        set { _fname = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Fname"); }
    }

    public string Lname
    {
        get { return _lname; }
        set { _lname = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Lname"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
 <Canvas>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedResult.Fname, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedResult.Lname, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Button Canvas.Left="90" Canvas.Top="65" Content="Remove" Click="button2_Click" Height="23" Name="button2" Width="75" />
    <Button Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="65" Content="Save" Height="23" Name="button1" Width="75"  />
    <ListView Name="listviewStudents" Canvas.Top="100" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentModel.std}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedResult}" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="fname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Fname}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="lname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Lname}"></GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Canvas>
```

I hope this info helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay first, I apologize if I do a poor job answering this. It's my first attempt.

So it looks like you've got the right idea, and most of what you've got will work. But it looks like you may have forgotten to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. And you might just consider using something like `List<GetStudent_Result>` instead, there is a lot less overhead than an ObservableCollection because you'll be implementing the NotifyPropertyChanged stuff yourself.

```
public class students : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    #region PropertyChanged EventHandler
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void NotifyPropertyChanged(String Property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Property));
    }
    #endregion

    private List<GetStudents_Result> stdb;
    public List<GetStudents_Result> std
    {
        get { return stdb; }
        set { stdb = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("std"); }
    }

    ...
```